# Detect tablet and smartphone

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, detection, browser-detection

I would like to know, what is the best way to detect tablets and smartphone at the moment?

Plugin, user agent detection, touch screen detection etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the top rated answer at this url:

[What is the best way to detect a mobile device in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-handheld-device-in-jquery)

Current methods from that thread:

```
var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);
```

Jquery:

```
$.browser.device = (/android|webos|iphone|ipad|ipod|blackberry|iemobile|opera mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()));
```

Comment: but aren't android tablet, a tablet, this code suggests that it is a mobile!